# Review audit: RecyclerView Endless Infinite Scrolling Issue

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9855809

The tell that prompted me to flag "close" as "why isn't this code working?" is there's code at an external link, and the included part is rather weighty.

The problem statement ("I am trying to implement Endless Infinite Scrolling with RecyclerView, but I am only getting first 10 records", with no reference links) is rather vague, too.

I.e. there's no MCVE "in the question itself" & a clear problem statement, just what the close reason says:

> Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must
>   include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the
>   shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself.**
>   Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other
>   readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is no link to external code, just to a JSON data file in the question or at least that how it is now.  It did start of that way with a series of external links but since has been edited into a good, well received question.  So unless your audit somehow showed a really early version of the question it looks fine to me.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf nitpick: "well-received" is not an argument here, audit UI conceals scores, I can only see (and thus judge) the content.